# intellij run project wtpwebapps not exist

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

i use intellij run project on tomcat,but when run tomcat,error throws

> D:\tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.59\apache-tomcat-7.0.59\bin\catalina.bat
>   run [2015-05-08 04:00:35,918] Artifact baseservice:war: Server is not
>   connected. Deploy is not available. [2015-05-08 04:00:35,918] Artifact
>   portal_ec:war: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available. Using
>   CATALINA_BASE:
>   "C:\Users\wyr.IntelliJIdea14\system\tomcat\Unnamed_portal_ec" Using
>   CATALINA_HOME:   "D:\tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.59\apache-tomcat-7.0.59"
>   Using CATALINA_TMPDIR:
>   "D:\tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.59\apache-tomcat-7.0.59\temp" Using
>   JRE_HOME:        "D:\jdk7\jre" Using CLASSPATH:
>   "D:\tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.59\apache-tomcat-7.0.59\bin\bootstrap.jar;D:\tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.59\apache-tomcat-7.0.59\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
>   Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:58851', transport:
>   'socket' 五月 08, 2015 4:00:37 下午
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin 警告:
>   [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting
>   property 'source' to
>   'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:portal_ec_indoor_branch' did not find a
>   matching property. 五月 08, 2015 4:00:37 下午
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin 警告:
>   [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting
>   property 'source' to
>   'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:BaseService_indoor_branch' did not find a
>   matching property. 五月 08, 2015 4:00:37 下午
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log 信息: Server
>   version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.59 五月 08, 2015 4:00:37 下午
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log 信息: Server
>   built:          Jan 28 2015 15:51:10 UTC 五月 08, 2015 4:00:37 下午
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log 信息: Server
>   number:         7.0.59.0 五月 08, 2015 4:00:37 下午
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log 信息: OS Name:
>   Windows 7 五月 08, 2015 4:00:37 下午
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log 信息: OS Version: 
>   6.1 五月 08, 2015 4:00:37 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log 信息:
>   Architecture:          amd64 五月 08, 2015 4:00:37 下午
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log 信息: Java Home:
>   D:\jdk7\jre 五月 08, 2015 4:00:37 下午
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log 信息: JVM Version:
>   1.7.0_71-b14 五月 08, 2015 4:00:37 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log 信息: JVM Vendor: 
>   Oracle Corporation 五月 08, 2015 4:00:37 下午
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log 信息:
>   CATALINA_BASE:
>   C:\Users\wyr.IntelliJIdea14\system\tomcat\Unnamed_portal_ec 五月 08,
>   2015 4:00:37 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>   信息: CATALINA_HOME:
>   D:\tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.59\apache-tomcat-7.0.59 五月 08, 2015
>   4:00:37 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log 信息:
>   Command line argument:
>   -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:58851,suspend=y,server=n
>   五月 08, 2015 4:00:37 下午
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log 信息: Command line
>   argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote= 五月 08, 2015 4:00:37 下午
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log 信息: Command line
>   argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099 五月 08, 2015 4:00:37
>   下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log 信息: Command
>   line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 五月 08, 2015
>   4:00:37 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log 信息:
>   Command line argument:
>   -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 五月 08, 2015 4:00:37 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log 信息: Command
>   line argument: -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 五月 08, 2015
>   4:00:37 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log 信息:
>   Command line argument:
>   -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Users\wyr.IntelliJIdea14\system\tomcat\Unnamed_portal_ec\conf\logging.properties
>   五月 08, 2015 4:00:37 下午
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log 信息: Command line
>   argument:
>   -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager 五月 08, 2015 4:00:37 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener
>   log 信息: Command line argument:
>   -Djava.endorsed.dirs=D:\tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.59\apache-tomcat-7.0.59\endorsed
>   五月 08, 2015 4:00:37 下午
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log 信息: Command line
>   argument:
>   -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\wyr.IntelliJIdea14\system\tomcat\Unnamed_portal_ec
>   五月 08, 2015 4:00:37 下午
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log 信息: Command line
>   argument:
>   -Dcatalina.home=D:\tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.59\apache-tomcat-7.0.59 五月 08, 2015 4:00:37 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener
>   log 信息: Command line argument:
>   -Djava.io.tmpdir=D:\tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.59\apache-tomcat-7.0.59\temp
>   五月 08, 2015 4:00:37 下午 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener
>   lifecycleEvent 信息: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which
>   allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on
>   the java.library.path:
>   D:\jdk7\jre\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Common Files\NetSarang;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA
>   Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS
>   Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program
>   Files\Broadcom\Broadcom 802.11 Network
>   Adapter\Driver;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL
>   SDK\2.0\bin\x64;;D:\jdk7\bin;D:\maven\apache-maven-3.2.3-bin
>   (1)\apache-maven-3.2.3\bin;. 五月 08, 2015 4:00:37 下午
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init 信息: Initializing
>   ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"] 五月 08, 2015 4:00:37 下午
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init 信息: Initializing
>   ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"] 五月 08, 2015 4:00:37 下午
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load 信息: Initialization processed
>   in 843 ms 五月 08, 2015 4:00:37 下午
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal 信息: Starting
>   service Catalina 五月 08, 2015 4:00:37 下午
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal 信息: Starting
>   Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.59 五月 08, 2015 4:00:37 下午
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext resourcesStart 严重: Error
>   starting static Resources java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document
>   base
>   D:\tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.59\apache-tomcat-7.0.59\wtpwebapps\BaseService_indoor_branch
>   does not exist or is not a readable directory     at
>   org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.setDocBase(FileDirContext.java:136)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:5141)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5326)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> 五月 08, 2015 4:00:37 下午 org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase
>   startInternal 严重: A child container failed during start
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/api]]
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:816)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/api]]
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
>     ... 6 more Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Error
>   in resourceStart()    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5327)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 6 more
>
> 五月 08, 2015 4:00:37 下午 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext
>   resourcesStart 严重: Error starting static Resources
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base
>   D:\tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.59\apache-tomcat-7.0.59\wtpwebapps\portal_ec_indoor_branch does not exist or is not a readable directory  at
>   org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.setDocBase(FileDirContext.java:136)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:5141)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5326)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> 五月 08, 2015 4:00:37 下午 org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase
>   startInternal 严重: A child container failed during start
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/EC]]
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:816)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/EC]]
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
>     ... 6 more Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Error
>   in resourceStart()    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5327)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 6 more
>
> 五月 08, 2015 4:00:37 下午 org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase
>   startInternal 严重: A child container failed during start
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)   at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:739)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:689)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:321)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455) Caused
>   by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed
>   during start  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:816)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 6 more
>
> 五月 08, 2015 4:00:37 下午 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start 严重:
>   The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to
>   start. org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start
>   component [StandardServer[8005]]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:689)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:321)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455) Caused
>   by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardService[Catalina]]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:739)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 7 more Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed
>   to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 9 more Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child
>   container failed during start     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     ... 11 more
>
> 五月 08, 2015 4:00:37 下午 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause 信息:
>   Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"] 五月 08, 2015 4:00:37 下午
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause 信息: Pausing ProtocolHandler
>   ["ajp-bio-8009"] 五月 08, 2015 4:00:37 下午
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal 信息: Stopping
>   service Catalina 五月 08, 2015 4:00:37 下午
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy 信息: Destroying
>   ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"] 五月 08, 2015 4:00:37 下午
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy 信息: Destroying
>   ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"] Disconnected from the target VM,
>   address: '127.0.0.1:58851', transport: 'socket' Disconnected from
>   server

i am novice to intellij,my tomcat config is like
[image]
[image]
[image]
how to run project on tomcat successfully?thanks your any help and suggestions !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uncheck  deploy application configured in tomcat instance in deployment tab and restart the server.
This will resolve your issue